# Xml error occur while consuming web service from android

Tags: android, web-services

Right now i am working with consuming web service from android by the method SOAP.

```
http://54.251.60.177/TMSWebService/MarginService.asmx
```

the above link is the exact web service's link which i am trying to consume.
The input values for this web service are

- fd:      01/01/2012
- td:      07/07/2012

This will return the answers in the form of xml.

But i am getting this message on my emulator

> ERROR : org.ksoap2.SoapFault:Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document(1,321).--->the string " is not a valid ALLXsd value.

What does this mean.How to overcome this issue? Can any one please let me know the solution, if you have?

Thanks for your precious time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build up an XML payload that you POST to the site.  This page: `http:// 54. 251. 60.177/TMSWebService/MarginService.asmx?op=GetTMSMargin` shows what it should look like.

If you look in the XML, you can see an element for the `fd` and `td` values to pass in.  I see both of those are a `dateTime`.  It looks like the web service was written with **.Net** and is using the `DateTime C#` type. It might make it easier (if you are also creating the web service) to use a more generic type, like string, which you will be able to build up the XML easier.